# Unhandled exception at 0x00C87963 in ....: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCE0

Tags: c++, exception, pointers, null

I'm not getting why this error happens:

```
while (currentNode != nullptr)
    currentNode = currentNode->parent;
```

The condition of my `while` loop should prevent it....

Comment: Why should it? Access violation occurs while reading `0xCCCCCCE0`, not `0x00000000`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`0xCCCCCCE0` looks a lot like `0xCCCCCCCC` which is what VisualC++ puts in any uninitialized local variable in debug builds.

So my guess is that you forgot to set to `nullptr` your `currentNode` or some `parent`.

Comment: I doubt it's the parent. You said it yourself, `0xCCCCCCCC` is used for uninitialised local variables.  Unless the nodes are created on the stack, which is doubtful. Uninitalised heap memory is filled with `0xBAADF00D`. :)

Comment: @James: It's impossible to say without seen the code, but maybe `parent` is assigned from a local temporary variable, and in some corner cases this variable is left uninitialized...

Comment: That's certainly possible, I suppose. :)

Answer (score 2):

If

```
currentNode->parent
```

contains an invalid pointer value this would crash with an access violation. A pointer could be set to an invalid value, it being a nullptr is not the only case.  Check where you set the value.